# Unable to get LoRa P2P up with ATSAMR34

Tags: avr, lora, atsam3x

I am new to LoRa.

We have a custom board built with the schematics provided for ATSAMR34. I am able to flash it with basic images and get it functioning for serial communication.

I tried to to build and flash images for LoRa P2P, as provided in
https://github.com/MicrochipTech/atsamr34_long_range_p2p

While the image is in, LoRa is not getting active. Both microcontroller boards are connected to the same laptop, on 2 different USB serial interfaces, COM6, COM8.

**output from COM 6**

```
Starting Node 1 of Simple Demo for LoRa P2P Stack ...
Full Function Device (FFD) operations
   RF Transceiver: SX_1276
   Demo Instruction:
           Power on the board until LED 1 lights up
           to indicate connecting with peer.
           Push Button 1 to broadcast message.
           LED 1 will be toggled upon receiving messages.

Periodic Transmission = Disable
Duty Cycling support = Disable

Before Initialize_Demo

-----------------------------------------------------
RF Parameters
 - Tx output power: 1
 - PA boost: 0
 - Spreading factor: SF7
 - Bandwidth (125kHz=7, 250kHz=8, 500kHz=9): 7
-----------------------------------------------------

Connecting Peer on Channel 1

Scan Channel 0
Scan Channel 1
 Scan Operation Status: 0 device found
Connect Operation Status: 0

Started Wireless Communication on Channel 1


My Address: 0xd8aa2b0f8e68fab5 PANID: 0x4321 Channel: 1

Connection   PeerLongAddress   PeerInfo   RxOnStatus

Before Stack_Init

Starting the processing
```

**Output from COM8**

```
Starting Node 1 of Simple Demo for LoRa P2P Stack ...
Full Function Device (FFD) operations
   RF Transceiver: SX_1276
   Demo Instruction:
           Power on the board until LED 1 lights up
           to indicate connecting with peer.
           Push Button 1 to broadcast message.
           LED 1 will be toggled upon receiving messages.

Periodic Transmission = Disable
Duty Cycling support = Disable

Before Initialize_Demo

-----------------------------------------------------
RF Parameters
 - Tx output power: 1
 - PA boost: 0
 - Spreading factor: SF7
 - Bandwidth (125kHz=7, 250kHz=8, 500kHz=9): 7
-----------------------------------------------------

Connecting Peer on Channel 1

Scan Channel 0
Scan Channel 1
 Scan Operation Status: 0 device found

Connect Operation Status: 0

Started Wireless Communication on Channel 1

My Address: 0xf0fbc24ed8d024db PANID: 0x4321 Channel: 1
Connection   PeerLongAddress   PeerInfo   RxOnStatus

Before Stack_Init

Starting the processing
```

Could some one help me out to get LoRa up?

I tried googling to understand how this is supposed to work, but I had not much of luck there.

Answer (score 0):

> Periodic Transmission = Disable

I haven't used these examples, but if there's no periodic transmission, nothing is going to happen... Could you try enabling it on one of the devices?

Comment: But, should it not find a peer for the P2P tx rx, during the initial bring up itself? I shall try with this enabled though.